# Solutions to $x^{p}\equiv1\pmod{p^k}$ except 1

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Are there any solutions to $x^{p}\equiv1\pmod{p^k}$, $p>2$ an odd prime, other than 1? 
If yes, are there any constraints on $x,p$?

Comment: [Closely related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1198386/11619). [Also this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2586908/11619). There are probably better matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ (1+pt)^p \equiv 1 \pmod {p^2}  $$
binomial expansion
$$ 1 + p \cdot pt + \frac{p^2 - p}{2} p^2 t^2 + \frac{p^3 -3p^2 +2p }{6} p^3 t^3 + \cdots  $$

Comment: you can generalize by $(1+p^{k-1})^{p} = 1 \mod p^k$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the comment

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little bit of modular arithmetic can do no harm. For an odd prime $p$ and any integer $r\ge 1$, the multiplicative subgroup $(\mathbf Z/p^r)^*$ of invertible classes of the ring $\mathbf Z/p^k$ has order $p^{k-1}(p-1)$. More precisely, $(\mathbf Z/p^k)^*$ is the direct product of  a cyclic subgroup $C_{p-1}$ of order $(p-1)$ and a cyclic subgroup $C_r$ of order $r=p^{k-1}$ generated by the class of $(1+p)$ (see e.g. S.Lang's "Algebra", ex.7 of chap. II). Thus the classes of the solutions of $x^p\equiv 1$ mod $p^k$ form a cyclic subgroup of order $1$ or $p^{k-2}$.